# Catch return code from composer validate in bash script

Tags: bash, composer-php

I'm trying to write a bash script that validates that composer.lock is up to date with composer.json before attempting to run `composer install`.

I have tried something like this:

```
if composer validate --no-check-all
  then echo "Composer validation failed..."
  exit 1;
fi

# composer install
```

That does exit my script on validation errors, however when validation passes I still get the following output:

```
./composer.json is valid
Composer validation failed...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: The test statement in the if block is missing a negation as correctly pointed out by Jeff Schaller. It doesn't affect the question much (since the exit code from composer validate is the same). I'm leaving the original wording as to not introduce further confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trusting too much the reliability of composer exit codes.
The command

```
composer validate --no-check-all
```

is returning zero and it's correct, because the command has no real problems in its execution. Consider capturing the output in a variable and reading it.

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT=$(composer validate --no-check-all)

if [[ "$OUTPUT" == *"is valid"* ]]; then
  echo "composer.json is valid (or whatever you want to do here)"
fi
```

Comment: This answer was very helpful, but there were a few more twists. The returned output from the validator contained the substring './composer.json is valid' even when warnings were found (...is valid, but...), so I had to check for the exact string. This was however colored green in the terminal and contained other special hidden chars. So it works with the following modifications: `OUTPUT=$(composer validate --no-check-all | sed 's/\x1B\[[0-9;]\{1,\}[A-Za-z]//g' | tr -d '[:cntrl:]')` and `if [[ "$OUTPUT" == "./composer.json is valid" ]]`

Comment: You can use `--no-ansi` option to disable colors.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I noticed was that the intention behind your `if` seems backwards. Your intention is to exit the script if the validation fails, indicated by the [return code from `composer`, which is documented as](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#process-exit-codes):

- 0: OK
- 1: Generic/unknown error code
- 2: Dependency solving error code

The [`if` conditional construct](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs) accepts a list of *test-commands* and ...

> if its return status is zero, the consequent-commands list is executed

So what you probably *intend* is to invert/negate that return code, so that you exit if you get a non-zero status from composer:

```sh
if ! composer validate --no-check-all
  then echo "Composer validation failed..."
  exit 1;
fi

# composer install
```

It seems in your situation that `composer validate ...` is returning 0 no matter whether it encountered an error or not. Perhaps you're being affected by [this bug report related to `brew`](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5893)?

Comment: I think you are exactly right. I did miss a negation in OP, and your linked issue is the culprit of the original problem i believe. I ended up testing for the exact string outputted by the validator as franzisk suggested, but stripped for special chars.